# Slope Fields in Mathematica and Sketching Appropriate Solution Curves

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

How would I plot the differential equation 
dv/dt = 32-1.6v, where v(0)=0

I also need to solve for the limiting velocity.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to find the limiting velocity. I know how to use vector plot but I'm unsure how to sketch the solution curve.

Comment: `I am having a hard time figuring out how to find the limiting velocity`. Terminal velocity is when $\frac{dv}{dt}=0$ (i.e. object is no longer accelerating). This means terminal velocity is the solution to $32= 1.6 v$ which is $20$ as verified by answer below.

Answer (score 2):

```
sol = DSolveValue[{v'[t] == 32 - 1.6 v[t], v[0] == 0}, v[t], t]
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
Limit[sol, t -> Infinity]
```